# Is there a command to check which pods have a service applied

Tags: kubernetes

I  have made a service.yaml and have created the service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cass-operator-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9042
      targetPort: 9042
  selector:
    name: cass-operator
```

Is there a way to check on which pods the service has been applied?

I want that using the above service, I connect to a cluster in Google Cloud running Kubernetes/Cassandra on external_ip/port (9042 port). But using the above service, I am not able to.

`kubectl get svc` shows

```
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
cass-operator-service   LoadBalancer   10.51.247.82   34.91.214.233   9042:31902/TCP   73s
```

So probably the service is listening on 9042 but is forwarding to pods in 31902. I want both ports to be 9042. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to follow labels and selectors.

Your pod has a label section, and the service uses it in the selector section. You can find some examples in the [official documentation for services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

You can find the selectors of your service with:

```
kubectl describe svc cass-operator-service
```

You can list your labels with:

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels
```

Comment: Thanks. So if the annotation in the service is `Selector:  name=cass-operator` and `kubectl get namespaces` returns `cass-operator` but `kubectl get pods -l name=cass-operator --show-labels` return `no resouces` then does that mean that I am using a wrong selector or something?

Comment: if the pods are in namespace: cass-operator, you need run: kubectl get pods -l "name=cass-operator" -n cass-operator

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is there a significance of namespace when specifying a selector? What should the selector be for such pods in a service. I want to associate a service with these pods but am not able to. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651374/how-do-i-access-my-cassandra-kubernetes-cluster-from-outside-the-cluster

Comment: I think this link will help you a lot to understand how namespaces work: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-organizing-with-namespaces. Review the section: Cross Namespace communication.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pods by querying with selector like following

```
kubectl get pods -l name=cass-operator
```

You can also list all pods which are serving traffic behind a kubernetes service by running

```
kubectl get ep <service name> -o=jsonpath='{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}' | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I % kubectl get pods -o=name --field-selector=status.podIP=%
```